# paged query leads to 404?

Tags: pagination, query, 404-error, blog, paged

As soon as I click the "2" on my pagination links I get a 404-error.
The url correctly changes to `http://mysite.com/?paged=2`

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop that displays the posts.
 */
?>


<ul class="post-items">
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post', 'wr_raffle'),
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('wrapper'); ?>>

            <div class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            <div class="post-excerpt text small"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

        </article>
        </li>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>      
</ul>

<div class="pagination wrapper clear">
<?php
    $endsize = $midsize = 1;
    $type = 'plain';
    $loop->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $loop->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

    // Sanitize input argument values
    if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
    $endsize = (int) $endsize;
    $midsize = (int) $midsize;

    // Setup argument array for paginate_links()
    $pagination = array(
        //'base'          => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
        'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
        'current'       => $current,
        'show_all'      => false,
        'end_size'      => $endsize,
        'mid_size'      => $midsize,
        'type'          => $type,
        'prev_next'     => false,
        //'paged'         => $loop->query_vars['paged']
    );

    echo paginate_links( $pagination );
?>
 </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I already refreshed my permalinks. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points you should try out:

- Remove the `'paged' => $loop->query_vars['paged']` from your `$pagination` array. It's not a parameter in the docs.
- Remove the `'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%')` from your `$pagination` array. I believe WordPress catches the paged parameter using the default page parameter. Which is it's default.

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) are the docs for the `paginate_links()` function you are using, i suggest you review them.

Lastly can you try accessing this url `http://mysite.com/?page=2` and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question. It's almost working now, two more details I need to ask for: Frist off, I changed the two lines like you mentioned and now the 404 error is gone and page two is shown. I also changed `'paged' => (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1,` However, the problem I'm having now is that page NR. 1 doesn't work anymore. So when reloading the home-page and I click on any number in the pagination everything works fine, but when clicking back on `1` nothing happens. When inspecting the element I see `<a class="page-numbers" href="">1</a>` How can I fix that?

Comment: You've only asked for one thing in the above comment, but I'll have a think on why page 1 isn't populating. Do you a url I can view or is it local?  What does the anchor tag for page two look like?

Comment: Anchortag for page2 looks like this … `<a class="page-numbers" href="?page=2">2</a>`

Comment: Before I clicked on Page Number Two: http://cl.ly/TNHx
After I clicked on Page Number Two: http://cl.ly/TN3o